# When to use property injection?

Tags: dependency-injection, ioc-container

1. When should I use property injection?
2. Should I use by default constructor injection if instance creation in fully controlled?
3. Am I right that using a constructor injection I write container-agnostic code?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> When should I use property injection?

You should use property injection in case the dependency is truly optional, when you have a Local Default, or when your object graph contains a cyclic dependency.

Property Injection however causes [Temporal Coupling](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/05/24/DesignSmellTemporalCoupling/) and when writing Line of Business applications, your dependencies should never be optional: you should instead apply the [Null Object pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern).

Neither should you use a Local Default, which is:

> "***A default implementation of an abstraction that's defined in the same assembly as the consumer.***" [DIPP&P, Section 4.2.2]

Local Defaults should not be used in Line of Business applications, because it complicates testing, hides the dependency, and makes it easy to forget to configure the dependency.

Neither should object graphs have cyclic dependencies. This is an [indication of a problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43472943/264697) in your application design.

> Should I use by default constructor injection if instance creation in fully controlled?

Yes. Constructor injection is the best way. It makes it very easy to see which dependencies a class has, makes it possible to make dependencies required, and prevents Temporal Coupling.

> Am I right that using a constructor injection I write container-agnostic code?

This is correct. Constructor injection allows you to delay the decision of which DI library to use, and [whether at all you use a DI library](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di/).

For a more detailed explanation of the above, and much more, read the book [Dependency Injection Principles, Practices, and Pattern](https://manning.com/seemann2/) (DIPP&P) by [Mark Seemann](https://blog.ploeh.dk/) and myself.

The usefulness of property injection is so limited, that while working on the book, Mark and I even discussed labeling Property Injection an anti-pattern. In the end we felt we couldn't make a case that was as strong as, for instance, [Ambient Context](https://freecontent.manning.com/the-ambient-context-anti-pattern/), which we did decide to describe as an anti-pattern in that edition. The case for Ambient Context was crystal clear, while being much muddier for Property Injection. But this is why, however, we added many warning notes to the Property Injection section (4.4), because we feel strongly Property Injection is not a good solution for the majority of cases.

There are several problems, though, that Property Injection seems to solve at first, such as the problem of [Constructor Over-Injection](https://jeffreypalermo.com/2010/01/constructor-over-injection-anti-pattern/) (where a constructor contains many dependencies). Constructor Over-Injection, however, is almost always caused by design deficits, such as:

- Class having [too many responsibilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle)
- [Lack of natural clusters](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/02/RefactoringtoAggregateServices/)
- [Choosing inheritance over composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)
- Application of [Cross-Cutting Concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-cutting_concern) through base classes instead of [Decorators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) or [Interceptors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interceptor_pattern)

Comment: Property injection should never be used in combination with default constructor, so it should be the only way to construct the object via DI container. So property injection perhaps could be used when you have too many dependencies and you do not want a very long constructor signature :)

Comment: @hB0 this is actually very bad advice. If you have a constructor with many args, your code is telling you that you are violating the Single Responsible Principle. Using properties will not fix the root problem: your class is too big; it should be split up in smaller, more focused classes.

Comment: You are correct but it's not an advice but the plausible case for using property injection in case the class is already messed up otherwise it's always better to use constructor injection. It's the same reason I commented but not answered as it's not a good approach.

Comment: @hB0 also you can read [How to avoid Dependency Injection constructor madness?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2420245/4805174) for help reducing the constructor "overinjecting" (sic!)...

Comment: @hB0: Only place I see for property injection appropriate is when you don't own the classes that you want to inject stuff into, i.e. WCF Proxy classes which are created/generated and instantiated outside of your code

Comment: @Tseng I don't think anybody can disagree with you.  When working in a framework that controls your application entry points and doesn't give you hooks into the different levels of the lifecycle, you are forced to do very weird (bad) things.  Nobody is happy about that.  Microsoft fails miserably in that category, which makes us sad pandas.

Answer (score 10):

The accepted answer argues in favor of *constructor injection* and takes a rather critical stance toward *property injection*. As such, it does not put focus on addressing the problems that *property injection* actually solves, if used correctly. Therefore I want to take the opportunity to address some of these points and also to provide some counter arguments to the accepted answer.

> When should I use property injection?

Imagine you have a project with 100+ controllers and all those controllers are extending a custom base controller (parent-service). In such a situation, where a service is extended by several child-services, employing *constructor injection* is a burden: For every constructor you create, you need to relay arguments to your parent-service's constructor. If you decide to extend your parent service's constructor signature you will also be forced to extend the signatures of all child-services' constructors.

To make this example more vivid, say you start your project with a base controller having a parameterless constructor.

- Now after a month you decide you want a logger service in your base controller. → Not only will you have to change the base controller constructor's signature but also those of your 100+ child controllers.
- Now again after a month you need access to a user service in your base controller → Again, you'll have to change the constructor signature of your 100+ child controllers.
- you get the point...

With *property injection* you can easily circumvent this whole inconvenience by simply adding the necessary properties to your parent service and letting your DI-mechanism handle the injection via reflection. As a side effect, this also greatly reduces the risk of merge conflicts (since the files touched is reduced to a minimum).

So far, I have been talking mostly about *controllers* but this example counts for any situation in which you have a service hierarchy – the deeper or broader this hierarchy gets, the greater the burden of constructor injection. However, avoiding service-hierarchies altogether may not always be a reasonable choice in a project.

One could say the decision between *property* and *constructor injection* is really a decision between a pragmatism and OOP "purism".

From a "purist" OOP perspective, the rule is (as stated in the accepted answer) to initialize all required fields of a class via its constructor in order to avoid granting any access to the newly created instance in an "unfinished" state (which may result in an exception being later thrown).

With reference to this rule, an OOP-purist has a valid point in saying that *property injection* (temporarily) leaves your services in an "unfinished" state (the timespan between when your constructor has returned and the moment your property is injected) and that this increases the risk that your application may break.

However, when talking about services managed by an IoC/DI container, this risk is practically reduced to zero if you consider that your DI-mechanism is responsible for resolving the dependency graph and wiring everything up before any user-action or api-request actually makes it into your system or needs being processed. For example, at the time a controller's action is invoked you can be sure that your services were properly wired up and injected into your controller's properties (given of course, that you configured them correctly in advance).

Also the argument that it is *only* possible with *constructor injection* to make your dependencies "required" is rather weak in a world where you are not responsible for manually injecting services into your classes but delegate this task to your IoC mechanism. Even worse, you may get a false sense of security because you stated via constructor that a `ServiceX` requires `ServiceY` – but if you forgot to register your `ServiceY` with your DI-mechanism, you merely get `null` injected into your `ServiceX`'s constructor.

Another "argument" against property injection is that it becomes harder for your fellow programmers to distinguish between properties that are managed by the DI mechanism and those which are simply non-DI-related. However, in this case you can just use a [marker attribute to "opt-in" for DI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53488056/2477619) or add short comments above your properties to clear things up, when the case is not clear. Also, in a service-class, it is rather unusual to have properties referring to other services that are not supposed to be manged by your DI mechanism.

Finally, as for saying that constructor injection makes unit testing easier (since you know what dependencies are required by a class), I would simply argue, that with *property injection* you will soon enough notice that you forgot to include a dependency when your tests begin to fail due to a certain service being undefined.

> Should I use by default constructor injection if instance creation in fully controlled?

With all the above being said, I think I can answer your second question with: **Not necessarily**.
It depends on your project's size, the kind of service-hierarchy you employ, how often your parent-services' dependencies change and how much time and resources you are willing to invest in managing parameters and passing arguments up the service-hierarchy.

> Am I right that using a constructor injection I write container-agnostic code?

Yes! – Under the premise that you are not injecting the container itself... which you shouldn't! ;)

---

All the above being said, here are some quotes from Martin Fowler's great [discussion on dependency injection](https://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html#ConstructorVersusSetterInjection) directly addressing the question of constructor vs setter/property injection, and I can fully subscribe to the last quote :)

> If you have multiple constructors and inheritance, then things can get particularly awkward. In order to initialize everything you have to provide constructors to forward to each superclass constructor, while also adding you own arguments. This can lead to an even bigger explosion of constructors.
>
> Despite the disadvantages my preference is to start with constructor injection, but be ready to switch to setter injection as soon as the problems I've outlined above start to become a problem.
>
> This issue has led to a lot of debate between the various teams who provide dependency injectors as part of their frameworks. However it seems that most people who build these frameworks have realized that it's important to support both mechanisms, even if there's a preference for one of them.

A final remark: If you, for some reason, want to switch back from *property injection* to *constructor injection*, no problem, you can always add a constructor with the parameters to be injected and assign the properties via your constructor – dead-simple.

Comment: A pragmatic answer.  Thank you for offering a different perspective.