# How to inject properties of one class into an object of another class?

Tags: java, class, object, dependency-injection

I want to find the size of files using the length() function of java.io.File class. But the file I have in my code is of a different package (com.xyz.archway.objectmodel.host.filesystem.File) and does not have any function for determining the file size. How do I inject properties of java.io.File into an object of com.xyz.archway.objectmodel.host.filesystem.File?

```
import java.io.File;
@EJB
private GetFilesForApplicationCommandBean getfilesforapp;
.
.
.
.
Set<com.xyz.archway.objectmodel.host.filesystem.File> setfile =  getfilesforapp.getFiles(tempapp, true);
for(com.xyz.archway.objectmodel.host.filesystem.File file : setfile)
    {
        size = size + file.length(); ----->error`       
    }
 return size;
```

Comment: does this other file have a getter for the file name (including its path)?

Comment: Why do u want to inject ? your File class can extend `java.io.File`

Comment: Agreed with @Rehman, just extend java.io.File

Comment: Related: [When to use property injection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39853478/264697).

Comment: @TimothyTruckle: It has a getter for just the name. There's another for the filesystem on which it is present but nothing with name and path together.

Comment: @Rehman: This class already extends another class so it can't extend java.io.File.

Comment: hopefully the name getter returns the complete path. in that case you can write: `size = new java.io.File(file).length();`