# ASP.NET Core automatically resolve all dependencies

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Is it possible to configure ASP.NET Core DI to resolve all classes?
Something similar to Autofac AnyConcreteTypeNotAlreadyRegisteredSource functionality.

I'm able to use Autofac in ASP.NET Core, but I do not want to add additional library to my application, because ASP.NET Core already has DI.

So basically instead of:

```
services.AddTransient<MyService>();
services.AddTransient<MyAnotherService>();
```

I'd prefer to do something like:

```
services.ResolveAll();
```

Comment: I suppose it could be done but there isn't already a convenient call to do it. I'm curious about what your particular use case is for this. What are you trying to accomplish and why do you think this is the best way to do it?

Comment: @ErikNoren it's how I usually use DI. I prefer do not create silly interfaces. So if I need only one implementation I will create a class instead of interface and class (to make test frameworks or DI frameworks happy). And almost all projects do not need several implementations for some functionality. So, if I want to inject some `Foo` class it's only `Foo` class I have. And my goal is to not configure DI at all for this. Actually I use Autofac for this `builder.RegisterSource(new AnyConcreteTypeNotAlreadyRegisteredSource());`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ASP.NET Core DI doesn't support auto-discovery and auto-registration and there is no plan to add those features (at least in near feature).

The main reason is that the .NET Core team tries to keep the built-in container as simple as possible and saves an easy/straitforward way for adding other DI containers.

Related SO question: [Property Injection in Asp.Net Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38459625/property-injection-in-asp-net-core)

Comment: That's not strictly true. You can scan and register dependencies found in assemblies using Scrutor. Check out IServiceCollection Scan.

Answer (score 12):

it seems we can start down this general automatic injection concept with a little reflection

i've filtered on "Provider" namespace and look for class names spelled the same as interfaces without "I", but of course season to your own taste

(this code works under an asp.net core 2.0 context)

```
  var allProviderTypes = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
    .GetTypes().Where(t=>t.Namespace != null && t.Namespace.Contains("Providers"));

  foreach(var intfc in allProviderTypes.Where(t=>t.IsInterface)) {
    var impl = allProviderTypes.FirstOrDefault(c=>c.IsClass && intfc.Name.Substring(1) == c.Name);
    if (impl != null) services.AddScoped(intfc, impl);
  }
```

Comment: thanks for sharing this, but question was about some build in method. I do not check if it's possible in 2.0, but looks like it's not.

Comment: Perhaps something like: var impl = allProviderTypes.FirstOrDefault(c=>c.IsClass && intfc.IsAssignableFrom(c) && !c.IsAbstract); would be a lot less brittle than assuming a naming convention.

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps Scrutor (Scanning feature) is close to what you`re looking for.
https://github.com/khellang/Scrutor

Answer (score 0):

Though using library like [Scrutor](https://github.com/khellang/Scrutor) or [SimpleInjector](https://docs.simpleinjector.org/en/latest/aspnetintegration.html) is better option, due to constraints I had to hand-roll auto registeration with reflection. I've tried to filter types by their namespace like [@Beej's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47720989/188256), but I have since learned that it is more effective to explicitly mark classes with attributes after editing `Startup.cs` 3 times in a row in order to tweak lifetime.

Here is example to collect classes marked with attributes:

```cs
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class TransientAttribute : Attribute {}
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class ScopedAttribute : Attribute {}
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class SingletonAttribute : Attribute {}

/*
Mark your classes with [Transient], [Scoped] or [Singleton] above then register like:
services.AddServicesByAttributes(typeof(Startup).Assembly);
*/

public static class AddByAttributeServiceCollectionExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddServicesByAttributes(this IServiceCollection services, Assembly assembly)
    {
        foreach (ServiceDescriptor d in assembly.GetTypes().SelectMany(MakeDescriptors).Distinct())
        {
            services.Add(d);
        }
        return services;
    }

    private static ServiceLifetime? FindLifetime(Type type)
    {
        return (
            type.IsDefined(typeof(TransientAttribute), false),
            type.IsDefined(typeof(ScopedAttribute), false),
            type.IsDefined(typeof(SingletonAttribute), false)
        ) switch
        {
            (false, false, false) => null,
            (true, false, false) => ServiceLifetime.Transient,
            (false, true, false) => ServiceLifetime.Scoped,
            (false, false, true) => ServiceLifetime.Singleton,
            _ => throw new ArgumentException($"Lifetime attribute specified more than once for {type}", nameof(type)),
        };
    }

    private static IEnumerable<ServiceDescriptor> MakeDescriptors(Type type)
    {
        if (FindLifetime(type) is not ServiceLifetime lifetime) { yield break; }

        if (type.IsGenericType)
        {
            // Handle Generic interfaces. Nested types not supported
            Type impl = type.GetGenericTypeDefinition();

            foreach (Type ifType in type.GetInterfaces())
            {
                // Strip type arguments
                Type service = ifType.IsGenericType ? ifType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() : ifType;

                yield return ServiceDescriptor.Describe(service, impl, lifetime);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Type impl = type;

            yield return ServiceDescriptor.Describe(impl, impl, lifetime);

            // Alias for interfaces
            // NB. Dispose() may be called more than once for shared instances
            Func<IServiceProvider, object> factory = (sp) => sp.GetRequiredService(impl);
            foreach (Type service in type.GetInterfaces())
            {
                yield return ServiceDescriptor.Describe(service, factory, lifetime);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I recommend [this book](https://livebook.manning.com/book/dependency-injection-principles-practices-patterns/chapter-15) by [@ploeh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/126014/mark-seemann)
and [@Steven](https://stackoverflow.com/users/264697/steven) that shows how to cope with ASP.NET Dependency injection.