# How to resolve a dependency in ASP.NET Core 2 using a key or factory?

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection

In Unity I can register multiple implementation of a given interface and later I can choose which implementation must be injected using a [Dependency("key")] attribute.

How can I achieve this in ASP.NET Core, using a key or using a factory?

Comment: This does not exist out of the box but you can check to see if Unity has an Asp.Net Core DI extension.

Comment: I would say the following quesion solves your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38459625/property-injection-in-asp-net-core

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Property Injection in Asp.Net Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38459625/property-injection-in-asp-net-core)

Comment: Unity can be easily integrated into ASP.NET Core, as [this Github repository](https://github.com/dotnetjunkie/Missing-Core-DI-Extensions/tree/master/src/SampleApplication.Unity) shows.