# What is the best way to merge into one same services injected in several constructors?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I'm working on a ASP.net core app and of course using dependency injection. Mainly injecting required services in constructors of pages or other services.
Some of these injected services are the same in almost every other constructor. For example there is the `ILogger<T>`, an `IAppInfo` holding some application wide information and there is an `IFileServices` used in many other services also.
So I end up with lots of injections in constructors, in some more than 7.
Question is, which is the best way to get rid of  all there parameters used in almost every constructor?

For now I have implemented another service with methods to get the required services:

```
    public interface IBasicsService<out T>
    {
        ILogger<T> GetLogger();
        ApplicationInfo GetApplicationInfo();
    }
```

implemented in:

```
    public class BasicsService<T> : IBasicsService<T>
    {
        private readonly ILogger<T> _logger;
        private readonly ApplicationInfo _info;

        // ReSharper disable once ContextualLoggerProblem
        public BasicsService(ApplicationInfo info, ILogger<T> logger) {
            _info = info;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public ILogger<T> GetLogger() {
            return _logger;
        }

        public ApplicationInfo GetApplicationInfo() {
            return _info;
        }
    }
```

Is that correct? Is it better to inject `IServiceProvider` and resolve services with this?
Thank you.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2420245/264697

Answer (score 1):

It is better not to use IServiceProvider it hides the dependency of your service
Assume that in some case you want to test this service
oops your are forced to Mock IserviceProvider.
The task that you wants to do has no differ from using ServiceLocator
This link can help you to see why it is not good to use ServiceLocator

[ServiceLocator is an antipattern](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/)

But if you are really wants to do that in any circumstances, Constructor injection is not the only way that you can use to inject dependency.
There is another way that called Property injection
This is a good discussion about property injection

[Property Injection in ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38459625/property-injection-in-asp-net-core)

Do not forget you can configure asp.net core to use some other IOC containers like castle Windsor or Unity that support property injection