# Autofac can inject property like @Resource in Spring?

Tags: c#, .net, autofac

Im using .Net6 with Autofac, now I have a controller and two service:

```cs
public class TestController {
    public ITestService TestService { get; set; }
    
    public string Test() => TestService.Test();
}
```

```cs
public interface ITestService {
    string Test();
}

public class TestService1 : ITestService {
    public string Test() => "Test1";
}

public class TestService2 : ITestService {
    public string Test() => "Test2";
}
```

I register them in `Module`:

```
public class AutofacModule : Autofac.Module {
    // use assembly scanning to register: https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/scanning.html
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder) {
        builder.RegisterControllers().PropertiesAutowired().AsSelf();

        builder.RegisterServices().AsImplementedInterfaces();
    }
}
```

Now `TestController.Get()` will return "Test1" because `TestService1` was injected. If I want to get `TestService2`(or other implemented instances), I need use constructor to take it.

In `Spring`, `@Resource("beanName")` can specify which instance will be inject, so I want to use an attribute to match instance`s name and inject it like Spring:

```cs
public class TestController {
    [Resource("TestService2")]
    public ITestService TestService { get; set; }
    
    // return "Test2"
    public string Test() => TestService.Test(); 
}
```

How can I do about that?

Comment: What is your problem with injection through the constructor?

Comment: @mohammad-aghazadeh No problem, but I should write many lines of code in constructor if I have multiple properties. Use attribute could be more easily and clearly.

Comment: Check this out, it might help :
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38459625/property-injection-in-asp-net-core#answer-53488056

Comment: @Mohammad Thanks, I tried about this. This solution can determine wheather the propery needs to be injected, but not which the instance what will be inject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Autofac.Annotation](https://github.com/yuzd/Autofac.Annotation) sloved it.

In short, it used `AutowiredAttribute` (extend `ParameterFilterAttribute`) and [pipeline phases](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/pipelines.html#pipeline-phases), the pseudo-code like this:

```cs
// Autofac.Module
protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder) {
    // get all components that has `[Component]` attribute in process;
    List<Type> components = GetComponents();
    foreach (Type c in components) {
        // register as self
        var registration = builder.RegisterType(c).WithAttributeFiltering();
        
        // get properties that has `[Autowired]` attribute
        List<PropertyInfo> properties = GetProperties(c);
        registration.ConfigurePipeline(pb => 
            pb.Use(PipelinePhase.Activation, MiddlewareInsertionMode.StartOfPhase,
                   // the callback will be execute when components was resolved
                   (context, next) => {
                       next(context);
                       object instance = context.Instance;
                       foreach (PropertyInfo info in properties) {
                           // get component from container by `Autowired`'s options
                           context.TryResolveService(..., out object obj);
                           info.SetValue(intance, obj);
                       }
                   }
            )
        );
    }
}
```